# Cannot pass a file uploaded from flask to VideoCapture()

Tags: python, opencv, flask, file-upload, video-processing

This is the server script that uses flask to let user upload a video file

```
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            file.save(file_path)
            abc.abc(file_path)

            flash('File successfully uploaded')
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            flash('Allowed file types are txt, pdf, png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
            return redirect(request.url)
```

`abc.abc(file_path)` uses the uploaded file and passes the file path to the `cv2.videocapture(file_path)` function. However after the file gets uploaded nothing such actually happens and the function call to `videocapture` doesn't get executed. Here is the code for the video capture part as a separate python script

```
class abc:

    def __init__(self, video_url):
        self.video_url = video_url


    def abc(self):

        # Define the video stream
        print('here')
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video_url)  # Change only if you have more than one webcams
```

How do I solve this problem of flask not passing the file to videocapture()?

Answer (score 0):

It calls init supposedly and doesn't take in the passed argument, a way around is to remove classes and directly import function from the module and pass the file path as the argument and it works.
Thanks [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/953482/kevin)